# Can't send emails using SwiftMailer (Symfony4): wrong SMTP parameters?

Tags: symfony, smtp, swiftmailer

I'm coding a small website using Symfony 4.
There's a simple contact form that is supposed to send emails, seemed easy until I realize I can't configure it ^^

I've followed Symfony doc instructions from here:
[https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html][1]

Meaning mainly having the Swift mailer dependy:

```
composer require mailer
```

And my Controller looks like this:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/contact", name="contact_handling")
 */
public function contactHandler(Request $request,  \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $contact = new Contact();
    $form = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $contact);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
            ->setFrom('send@example.com')
            ->setTo('myownemail@hotmail.fr')
            ->setBody("plopppp mail")
        ;

        $mailer->send($message);
        $contact = $form->getData();
        return $this->render('home.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
    return $this->render('home.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
```

No matter what it does next in the return (I'm also trying to figure out how to avoid the page reload and just return an answer like "OK" or "not OK" then my Javascript pops up a message)

For dev environment (I'll have the same problem when moving to prod by the way),
my .env conf file has this parameter:

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://smtp-mail.outlook.com:587?encryption=tls&username=myownemail@hotmail.fr&password=mypwd
```

while trying to use my own email account, which could be my problem

Smtp address, port and encryption are some parameters found on website like this one:
[https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-the-outlook-com-smtp-server-settings-1170671][1]

Of course, I've never received anything. 
If someone familiar whith this could help me it would be very nice :)

I'm using Windows10 + PhpStorm + php7 + built-in symfony server

Thanks!

Edit:
Output from: php bin/console debug:config SwiftmailerBundle

```
swiftmailer:
default_mailer: default
mailers:
    default:
        url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
        spool:
            type: memory
            path: 'C:\www\h4h\var\cache\dev/swiftmailer/spool'
            id: null
        transport: smtp
        command: '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs'
        username: null
        password: null
        host: localhost
        port: null
        timeout: 30
        source_ip: null
        local_domain: null
        encryption: null
        auth_mode: null
        delivery_addresses: {  }
        logging: true
        delivery_whitelist: {  }
```

Edit 2:
I've just tried putting the conf in the config/packages/swiftmailer.yaml without more success, but at least, php bin/console debug:config SwiftmailerBundle outputs the correct info:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    username: mylogin
    password: mypwd
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    encryption: ssl
    auth_mode: login
    spool:
        type: file
        path: '%kernel.cache_dir%/swiftmailer/spool'
    sender_address: ~
    antiflood:
        threshold: 99
        sleep: 0
    delivery_addresses: []
    disable_delivery: ~
    logging: '%kernel.debug%'
```

Comment: of course, "Hello everyone" (can't edit my post?)

Comment: If you're trying to say you wanted to say that in your post, please be aware that Stack Overflow actually dicourages that, and pleasantries and chitchat often get edited out from questions as part of the user-driven quality assurance process here. You *should* be able to edit your own post, though...?

Comment: Hi tripleee,
Nothing but basic politeness that missed in my post.
I should be able to edit it, but nothing is saved when I proceed, that's the reason.
(edits here work fine)

Comment: @Potemkin: You can and should edit your question if you need to. Regarding your problem: Can you please add the output of `bin/console debug:config SwiftmailerBundle` (obfuscating the secret parts)?

Comment: Thanks lxg. Tried again edit 1st post, in fact working except if I add something on the beginning (before my initial text). Anyway, I've added my output on my post.
Thanks for the command advice, it shows putting all information on MAILER_URL makes it doesn't recognize some info, such as login/pwd ?

Comment: Edit 2:
I've just tried putting the conf in the config/packages/swiftmailer.yaml
No more success :/

Comment: Oh yes, if you try to edit in "Hello everyone" it will block that specifically for the reasons I outlined above. Politeness is a virtue but it is only distracting in this use case and so it is discouraged.

Comment: Oh I see now, didn't understand it that way in first! :)

Comment: I am not sure I support this directive but yes, you can edit or post a question saluting but it will get chopped from the text.